# Dnx running always set as x86, but it is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, coreclr

I am trying to run a project in ASP.NET 5 and always getting the below error. My laptop is Windows 10 64 bit machine. But dnx always set as x86 and changing the default alias command doesn't work in my case.

**c:\Projects\HelloWorld>dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta8 -arch x64 -r clr p**

Updating alias 'default' to 'dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8'

[dnx error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIBGu.png)

Even after I was setting up my default run time as x64 but still I am getting the error as run time conflict.

Comment: If you do `dnvm list` does it display the right architecture as your default?

Comment: You should show what is in your `project.json` because it's telling you that the active runtime isn't compatible with whatever you specified in your project.json.  I don't know why you want to use dnvm alias.  I think you want to use `dnvm use` to select the active one. Spend a minute reading `dnvm help`.

Comment: @user5555457 You should copy the error instead of posting an image so its easier to read in mobile browsers

Answer (score 2):

Use `dnvm use` instead of `dnvm alias`:

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8 -r clr -arch x64
```

Comment: No luck :( i got the below error when i used dnvm use command                     C:\Users\Selva>dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8 -r clr -arch x64 p
dnvm-use : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'p'.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\dnvm.ps1:1453 char:13
+             & "dnvm-$cmd" @cmdargs
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [dnvm-use], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,dnvm-use

Comment: I think you just want `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8 -r clr -arch x64` and leave of the p crap, whatever you meant the p to mean it means nothing.  Just because your laptop is 64 bit windows doesn't mean you need to force a 64 bit runtime, especially if you didn't install one.  You should show the output of `dnvm list` so we can see what you actually have installed.

Comment: Please find below the para for the dnvm list details which you have requested. kindly do the needful.